# Scala package issue

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, import, package

I have a `Words` package containing word types (`Noun`, `Verb`, `Adjective` ...) but although I imported `Words._` and my IDE find well every classes, I have this error:

```
Error:(11, 40) type mismatch;
found   : Word (in Words) 
required: Word (in <empty>) 
  val adj: Word = WordFactory.produce("big")
```

Thing is, I have nothing out of my packages (in the `<empty>` package).
I'm using IntelliJ Idea CE.

This is my test:

```
test("Adjective") {
    val expected: Adjective = Adjective("big", "big", "m", "sp")
    val test: Word = WordFactory.produce("big")
    assert(test == expected)
}
```

If i clarify `val test: Words.Word` my test fail:

```
Adjective(big,big,m,sp) did not equal Adjective(big,big,m,sp)
ScalaTestFailureLocation: WordFactoryTests at (WordFactoryTests.scala:13)
Expected :Adjective(big,big,m,sp)
Actual   :Adjective(big,big,m,sp)
```

`Adjective` is a case class so with the same args it just can't be different..
For information, I have other tests (testing other case classes like `Noun`) which are identical but works well.

**EDIT:**
Problem don't seems linked to scalatest, even in a main, I have the error (with `<empty>`).

This is my file `Word.scala`:

```
package Words

abstract class Word() {
  val correctWriting: String
  val lemma: String
  var currentWriting: String = correctWriting

  def isCounterfeited: Boolean = this.currentWriting != this.correctWriting

  def counterfeit()
}
```

and `Adjective.scala`:

```
package Words

case class Adjective(correctWriting: String, lemma: String, gender: String, number: String) extends Word {
  override def counterfeit: Unit = Counterfeiters.Adjective.counterfeit(this)
}
```

The complete code is on [my GitHub](https://github.com/vnourdin/WordCounterfeiter).

Comment: I think Scalatest equality is a complex subject and I would not be sure == uses the case class comparison. Can you try using === instead?

Comment: Unfortunately `===` doesn't change anything, nice try anyway.  
I can take a look at another test suite, I'm using `FunSuite` for the moment.

Comment: I am afraid without seeing more of your code it is hard to give any advice. Can you post at lease Adjective source? Try reducing the problem source to the bare minimum, so that you can post it here.

Comment: Done, I haven't reduced my code as it was already short.

Comment: Close, but not there yet - the code does not produce the error yet. Where is the `WordFactory`, or how can I produce the error? What is `Counterfeiters`?

Comment: I added a link to my GitHub, where the up-to-date code is.
WordFactory take a String and return a Word of the appropriate type, and Counterfeiters apply mistake on words, depending on their type.

Comment: When I run your project from SBT using `test` task, all tests pass. Are you sure it demonstrates the problem?

Comment: When I added your test (with added Words. prefixes), the test fails with understandable reason `Adjective(big,big,e,sp) did not equal Adjective(big,big,m,sp) `. When I change `"m"` to `"e"` it passes.

Comment: In my case it's Adjective("gros", "gros", "m", "sp").  
With Words. prefixe it work always but without no, I don't understand this point as I `import Words._`

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you write both with `Words.` prefix and without it. If you want an answer, prepare a small case demonstrating the problem. The GitHub project you link to is showning no problems and it is unclear how to modify it to show them - and it is too large anyway. Extract just the classes needed to demonstrate the issue, and reduce the classes to the bare minimum. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I suppose from what you say that my problem I coming from some IDE cache files, before I wasn't using packages. I'll try to clean the IDE project config

Comment: In the end, it was a config weird stuff, renaming the project solved it...  
Thanks a lot for your help @Suma !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I renamed my project and it solved this problem. Weird IDE stuff, I was working without package before, and the reorganization in packages broke something.
I you face similar problem try yo clean you IDE!